# ECS with Go - circular imports

Tags: entity-system, go

I'm exploring both Go and Entity-Component-Systems. I understand how ECS works, and I'm trying to replicate what seems to be the go-to document of ECS, namely http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/

For performance, the document recommends to use static arrays of every component type. That is, not arrays of component interfaces (arrays of pointers). The problem with this in Go is circular imports.

I have one package, *ecs*, which contains the definitions for **Entity**, **Component** and **System** types/interfaces as well as an **EntityManager**. Another package, *ecs/components*, contains the various components. Obviously, the *ecs/components* package depends on *ecs*. But, to declare arrays of specific components in **EntityManager**, *ecs* would depend on *ecs/components*, therefore creating a circular import.

Is there any way of avoiding this? I am aware that normally a high level system should not depend on lower systems. I'm also want to point out that using an array of pointers is probably fast enough for my purposes, but I'm interested in possible workarounds (for future reference)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

> For performance, the document recommends to use static arrays of every
>   component type.

I'm just going to start off saying that I may be blind, but I ctrl+f'd and read that document multiple times and didn't see anything close to that. (Certainly some optimizations could be made this way with regards to things like avoiding cache misses, but I'm dubious it in any way outweighs the clerical overhead).

There's the easy answer to the exact question you asked first, the `.` import. Any package with an import statement like `import . "some/other/package"` will treat that package's contents as its own, ignoring circular dependencies. **Don't do this**.

Unfortunately, without merging the packages, you won't be able to do this (without using interfaces, I mean). Don't fear, though. The article you posted explicitly says this under "implementation details".

> Giving each component a common interface means deriving from a base
>   class with virtual functions. This introduces some additional
>   overhead. Do not let this turn you against the idea, as the additional
>   overhead is small, compared to the savings due to simplification of
>   objects.

It's outright telling you to use interfaces (okay, C++ virtual inheritance, but close enough). It's okay, it's necessary. Especially if you want two slightly different AI components or something, it's a godsend then.